# How to select all empty cells below current selected until first non-empty cell in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, vba, microsoft-office-2010

I am trying to write a macro that copies the current cell and pastes the text into every empty cell below it until it reaches the first non-empty cell.

So if I had "Apple" in cell B2 and "Orange" in cell B8 and "Banana" in cell B11, when I select B2 and run the macro, cells B3:B7 are filled with "Apple" and when I run the macro with B8 selected, cells B9:B10 are filled with "Orange".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want a macro for this trivial task? Try the following and see if it would work for you:

- Insert a new `C` column in to your sample sheet with "Apple",
  "Orange" and "Banana"
- Enter `=IF(B2<>"",B2,C1)` formula into the `C2`
- Select `C2` and drag/fill the formula down for how many rows you need